# How to get path for graphic?

Tags: graphics

hi every one i have big problem i want to include some graphics in my PDF but there are in other folder i want to include them with out moving them 
i use commend

```
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \graphicpath{c:/Documents/mypicture/mypicture1.jpg}
 \begin{document}
 \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{mypicture1.jpg}
 \end{document}
```

but i have problem please help me
i use xe-latex compiler.
and what happen if they are more than one image for example :c:/Document/my pictures/picture1.jpg c:/Document/my pictures/picture2.jpg

Comment: `\graphicpath{{c:/Documents/}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths in `\graphicspath` has to be surrounded by braces and should end with the directory separator. Also they do *not* contain the image file names:

```
\graphicpath{{c:/Documents/}}
```

The syntax for `\graphicspath` is documented in section "4.5 Other commands in the graphics package" in the LaTeX guide for the graphics packages, [`grfguide.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/graphics/grfguide.pdf).

If the path or image file contain spaces, then package `grffile` should be loaded in addition:

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

Comment: what happen if my path be longer??

Comment: for example c:/Document/my pictures/picture1.jpg

Comment: and what happen if they are more than one image 
for example :c:/Document/my pictures/picture1.jpg
                     c:/Document/my pictures/picture2.jpg

Comment: @alish The full path can be specified in `\includegraphics`, the paths in  `\graphicspath` usually contain directories.

Comment: @alish path should be `\graphicpath{{c:/Documents/mypictures/}}` --- notice the slashes direction and the fact that the path is the *folder*. Avoid using folders with spaces in their name (it can work, it could not work, simply avoid it). Now you can include all the graphics you want from that folder simply with their name